# Creating text & button controls dynamically and populating text box with date values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datepicker, onclientclick

I currently have a VB.Net application that builds textboxes dynamically.
I need to display a button control which will display a datepicker and then populate the corresponding textbox with the selected date value.

I am creating the btnCalendar dynamically since there are more than one calendar buttons on a particular page, so `btnCalendar.ID = tab.ID & grdRowID`

```
Protected Sub DisplaySearchWindow()
Dim ddl As DropDownList
Dim txt As TextBox
Dim cal As Calendar
Dim btnCalendar As Button 

Select Case iIndex
  Case 1
     Dim cv As New CompareValidator
     txt = New TextBox
     txt.ID = "txt" & UserName & grdRowID.Name
     cv.ControlToValidate = txt.ID
     btnCalendar = New Button
     btnCalendar.ID = "btnCalDisplay" & tab.ID & grdRowID
     btnCalendar.Text = "+"
     btnCalendar.ToolTip = "click to view calendar" 
     btnCalendar.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javascript:return ShowAlert('Hi');")
     c.Controls.Add(cv)
     c.Controls.Add(txt)
     c.Controls.Add(btnCalendar)
```

When building the button control in codebehind, I have `btnCalendar.OnClientClick = btnCalendar.Visible = True`

When I run the application and click btnCalendar, I get an error message **JavaScript runtime error: 'True' is undefined**.

How can I display the DatePicker control using btnCalendar.OnClientClick (or any other alternative) from codebehind ?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any ASP.NET, but shouldn't your markup for the button include something like 

`OnClick = Mysub`

and then your codebehind is 

`Private Sub Mysub()
btncalendar.Visible = true
End Sub`


As I say, it's been a good long time since I've done any web development, so I could be completely wrong.

When you debug the code you've got, what happens?

Comment: Put option explicit on. It's the same as if you wrote: btnCalendar.OnClientClick = (btnCalendar.Visible = True).ToString()

Comment: @the_lotus I tried your suggestion, but same error "JavaScript runtime error: 'True' is undefined"

Comment: @user3929962 it wasn't a suggestion, it was to explain why the value "True" is inserted in the OnclientClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to an alternative (which from your post, you indicate so), you can try this:

```
Select Case iIndex
  Case 1
     Dim cv As New CompareValidator
     txt = New TextBox
     txt.ID = "txt" & UserName & grdRowID.Name
     txt.cssclass="DateValue"
     cv.ControlToValidate = txt.ID
     c.Controls.Add(cv)
     c.Controls.Add(txt)
```

Then on your aspx page, follow the example on the [JQueryUI page](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind the code should be:

```
Sub btnCalendar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalendar.Click

 btnCalendar.Visible = True

end sub
```

or you can try this in your asp page:

```
 <%@ page language="VB"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <script runat="server">
      Sub btnCalendar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
         btnCalendar.Visible = True
      End Sub
    </script>
    <html>
    <head>

</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:button id="btnCalendar" runat="server" onclick="btnCalendar_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```